# Convert pandas dataframe into transposed tabular format

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transpose `pandas.Dataframe` into transposed tabular format using `pandas` functionality
So all the phone numbers should be mentioned under column `MSISD` and `play_id` should have values of column names if its phone1 or phone2 or so on.

df is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['1', '2', '3'],
    'play_id': ['20002075', '601731', '601731'],
    'phone1': ['0900031349', '', ''],
    'phone2': ['090891349', '', ''],
    'phone3': ['', '', ''],
    'phone4': ['', '', ''],
    'phone5': ['', '088235311', ''],
    'phone6': ['', '', ''],
    'phone7': ['', '', '088235311']
})
```

Expected output should be

```
   id           play_id  msisd
1:  1            phone1  0900031349
2:  2            phone2  090891349
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with remove values with empty strings by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.melt(['id','play_id'], value_name='val', var_name='phone')
df1 = df1[df1['val'] != '']
#if empty strings are NANs 
#df1 = df1[df1['val'].notna()]
print (df1)
   id   play_id   phone         val
0   1  20002075  phone1  0900031349
3   1  20002075  phone2   090891349
13  2    601731  phone5   088235311
20  3    601731  phone7   088235311
```

Or use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with replace empty strings to missing values:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['id','play_id'])
        .replace('', np.nan)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='val')
        .rename(columns={'level_2':'phone'})
        )

print (df1)
  id   play_id   phone         val
0  1  20002075  phone1  0900031349
1  1  20002075  phone2   090891349
2  2    601731  phone5   088235311
3  3    601731  phone7   088235311
```